# System OutOfMemoryException SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have following system configuration:

- RAM - 64GB
- CPU - Intel Xeon OS - 64 Bits
- Windows Server 2012 R2

I'm developing report in VS Data Tool 2015.

My report needs to fetch around 700K rows and 135 columns.

If I'm selecting top 10 records its displaying perfect. However, if I am doing

```
SELECT * 
FROM table name
```

I get an error (from the development preview):

> An error occurred during local report processing.Exception of type "System.OutOfMemoryException" was thrown.

Is there any specific limit for SSRS rows and columns?

Same report if I'm deploying, and running from report server URL, it's running continuously without any result.

Hope I have explained it correctly? Is there any additional information required?

As per MS `rsReportServer.config` should be here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file)
However, unable to get this. Where can I find the `rsReportServer.config` file ?

Is there any settings needs to be changed? How can I resolve this issue?

Note: I'm getting all records from query executing from SSMS in 5 minutes.

Comment: Question is, do your clients want all this data at once and if so is rendering in the browser only to download the optimal solution? I am being conservative here...if each column came out to contain only 64 bytes (primitive types) and you were only rendering to csv then your payload would be 6.048 GB. This value could easily double if dealing with formats such as PDF and/or word, not to mention text blobs and what not. Do you have any wiggle room to chop this down a little?

Comment: do your clients want all this data at once - Yes. Further more, I'm sorry, I really not able to understand your other comments starting from "I am being conservative here" Could you please clearly elaborate ? Thanks.